como mostrar aprobado o no aprobado al listar notas de estudiantes
Cordial saludo, espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo la siguiente situación
en un atabla se lista a un grupo de estudiantes los cuales son consultados a una base de datos, estos estudiantes tienen asignada una nota final y a su vez tiene un estado que debería mostrar pendiente sino tiene nota, aprobado si el valor es 3 o superior y en caso contrario mostrar no aprobado.
con el código javascript que utilizo para mostrar el estado funciona pero solo con el primer registro, a los demás registros le pone el mismo valor del primero independientemente que en la nota tenga un valor de 3 o superior que seria el puntaje de aprobación.
El codigo para mostrar el listado de estudiantes en la tabla es el siguiente:
<table id="requestdata" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead class="GrupoHeadTabla" id="TablaResultados">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="90" align="center">Codigo</td>
                                        <td width="300" align="center">Asignatura</td>
                                        <td width="100" align="center">Nivel</td>
                                        <td width="100" align="center">Nota final</td>
                                        <td width="120" align="center">Estado</td>
                                        <td width="100" align="center">Acciónes</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="GrupoBodyTabla">
                                    <?php
                                    require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
                                    $consulta = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbpensumcontenido WHERE Pensum = :nombPensum");
                                    $consulta->execute([':nombPensum'=>$pensum['idPensum']]);
                                    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                        if(empty($resultado)){
                                        ?>
                                            <script>
                                            var tablaResultados = document.getElementById('TablaResultados');
                                            var fondoResultados = document.getElementById('Resultados');
                                            tablaResultados.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                            fondoResultados.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
                                            </script>
                                            <div id="MensajeNohayInformacion"> Actualmente no hay asignaturas para mostrar. El estudiante no se encuentra matriculado en el programa de formación.</div>
                                        <?php
                                        } else {
                                        foreach($resultado as $CPensum){
                                        ?>
                                        <td width="90" align="center" valign="middle">
                                            <?php echo $CPensum['asignatura']?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="300" align="left" valign="middle" class="name">
                                            <?php
                                            require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
                                            $consultaAsig = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbasignatura WHERE codigoAsignatura = :codAsig LIMIT 1;");
                                            $consultaAsig->execute([':codAsig'=>$CPensum['asignatura']]);
                                            $resultadoAsig = $consultaAsig->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                            foreach($resultadoAsig as $asignatura){
                                            ?><?=$asignatura['nombreAsignatura']?><?php }; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="100" align="center" valign="middle">
                                            <?php
                                            require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
                                            $consultaNivel = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbnivelsemestre WHERE idNivelSemestre = :codNivel LIMIT 1;");
                                            $consultaNivel->execute([':codNivel'=>$CPensum['nivel']]);
                                            $resultadoNivel = $consultaNivel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                            foreach($resultadoNivel as $nivel){ ?><?=$nivel['nombreNivelSemestre']?><?php }; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="100" align="center" valign="middle">
                                            <input type="text" name="nota" id="nota" class="inputTextoCentrado" value="<?php echo $CPensum['nota']?>" readonly>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="120" align="center" valign="middle">

                                            <script>
                                                var nota = document.querySelectorAll('#nota').value;

                                                       if(nota === "") {
                                                            document.write("Pendiente");
                                                        } else if(nota >= 3) {
                                                            document.write("Aprobado");
                                                        } else {
                                                            document.write("No aprobado");
                                                        }


                                            </script>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="100" align="center" valign="middle">
                                            <select name="asignarAsig" id="asignarAsig">
                                                <option>Matricular</option>
                                                <option>Homologar</option>
                                                <option>Habilitar</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                          };
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                 </tbody>
                            </table>


He agregado la etiqueta php, espero que eso ayude a que respondan tu pregunta con el [mcve] que proporcionas

Gracias Ruslan López,  Espero si me puedan ayudar.

A primera vista, suponiendo que tu código genera varios inputs con el mismo id="nota" ahí tienes el error, porque los IDs de los elements debe ser únicos. Si tú tienes varios con el mismo id, y haces algo como querySelectorAll('#nota') te va a tomar el primero que encuentre entre varios, o cualquiera, quien sabe, pero no el dato exacto que quieres. Debes replantear un poco tu lógica. Por ejemplo, puedes obtener la nota por otro valor único del estudiante, digamos, su ID, y alcanzar por ahí los elementos adyacentes...

... también puedes generar ids de notas secuenciales, poniendo un contador, pero creo que esto es poco práctico. En la pregunta falta contexto para entender cómo tienes montada tu interfaz, pero, imaginando un contexto, digamos que haces click en un estudiante, y luego quieres saber su nota, generar ids secuenciales no te servirá de mucho, en cambio, la puedes buscar en los elementos adyacentes de ese estudiante. O, se puede también asignar el dato en el código de servidor, por ejemplo en un atributo data-. Hay mil formas, pero falta contexto en tu pregunta.
